# TFS Not all collection level administration is exposed in the web experience

Tags: tfs

I installed TFS on my machine but I am not able to create projects because of the mentioned message

`Not all collection level administration is exposed in the web experience. For all administration operations at the collection level please use the Administration Console on your Team Foundation Server.`

I have given full permissions to all the available groups and users but still not getting the option to create projects so can some one help me

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you have not provided the user who is trying to create the new project permission in the TFS admin console. try that https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f05ba53b-35dc-4ebc-9ab2-51c3581f63a7/not-able-to-create-the-project?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: I have all those but still no luck please find the attached images

Answer (score 2):

You're running TFS 2015 RTM. Creating team projects via the web was only an option added in TFS 2015 Update 2.

Unless you upgrade to TFS 2015 Update 2 or later, you'll have to use Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 to create new team projects.